# How to return NULL in regex

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I would like to return NULL value after the delimiter `**` is not found in the string using Oracle. I have the string

```
 first path**second path
```

I want to cut the string after delimiter `**` and I use this regexp

```
 REGEXP_SUBSTR(str , '[^**]*$')
```

The result is correct.It return `second path`. But what I need is when the string has no delimiter `**`(e.g. firstpathsecondpath) and need to return `NULL`. What should I change my regexp? Currently the regexp return the whole string when there is no delimiter `**`.

Comment: Just a remark: your regexp is not correct - it matches any sequence of non-asterisk characters at the end of the string (you can test it with `third*fourth` - it will return `fourth`).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt No I already tested what you said. It return NULL

Comment: No, it doesn't: `select REGEXP_SUBSTR('third*fourth' , '[^**]*$') from dual` returns `fourth`.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Ok. I agreed both double * and single * work with this expression [^**]*$ right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query will return NULL if two asterisks followed by some text are not found in the source string:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT 'first path**second path' text FROM DUAL
           UNION
           SELECT 'third pathfourth path' text FROM DUAL)
SELECT SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.text,'(\*{2})(.+)'),3)
FROM t
```

Comment: Note that `[\*\*]{2}` is equivalent to `\*{2}` or `\*\*`.

Comment: Totally rigth @AndreaCorbellini. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You get the original string when there is no match.  Use a select case, testing the double-splat.  when found, return the second part, when not, return NULL:

```
SQL> with tbl(rownbr, str) as (
     select 1, 'first path**second path' from dual
     union
     select 2, 'third pathfourth path' from dual
   )
   select rownbr, str, case REGEXP_INSTR(str , '\*\*')
     when 0 then
       NULL
     else
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(str , '[^**]*$')
      end data
   from tbl;

    ROWNBR STR                     DATA
---------- ----------------------- -----------------------
         1 first path**second path second path
         2 third pathfourth path

SQL>
```